# Экранирование кавычек

Tags: php

Хочу показать погоду с гугла. Нашел скрипт разбивки хмл с погодой. Хочу показать это на сайте. Но что-то явно не так, и видимо с кавычками. А на серваке отрубили показ ошибок, и я не пойму что и где именно не так.

```
function getWeather() {
$requestAddress = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Paris";
$xml_str = file_get_contents($requestAddress,0);
$xml = new SimplexmlElement($xml_str);
$count = 0;
$res = '';
$res .="<div id=\"weather\">";
  foreach($xml->weather as $item) {
    foreach($item->forecast_conditions as $new) {
      $res .= '<div class="weatherIcon">';
      $res .= '<img src="http://www.google.com/' .$new->icon['data'] . '"/><br/>';
      $res .= $new->day_of_week['data'];
      $res .= '</div>';
    }
  }
$res .="</div>";
return $res;
}
```

Comment: Вам разметка ответила =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//$res = ";
$res = '';
```

Comment: Все еще где-то ошибка.

Comment: На другом серваке где ошибки показываются увидел вот что:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /index.php:40 Stack trace: #0 /index.php(40): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('<?xml version="...') #1

Comment: Ну перевести-то вы можете? Строка не может быть распарсена как xml. Значит, в самой xml ошибка.

Comment: Гугл отдает плохую хмл? :)

Comment: см. выше )

Comment: Я оплашал :) 
кодировка не та была $xml = new SimplexmlElement(iconv("windows-1251","UTF-8",$xml_str));